# System Error Pop Up Everytime I boot into it - Ubuntu 23.10

Tags: system

Neo Fetch Results -

```
            .-/+oossssoo+/-.               khushal@khushal-pc 
        `:+ssssssssssssssssss+:`           ------------------ 
      -+ssssssssssssssssssyyssss+-         OS: Ubuntu 23.10 x86_64 
    .ossssssssssssssssssdMMMNysssso.       Host: MS-7D22 1.0 
   /ssssssssssshdmmNNmmyNMMMMhssssss/      Kernel: 6.5.0-9-generic 
  +ssssssssshmydMMMMMMMNddddyssssssss+     Uptime: 2 mins 
 /sssssssshNMMMyhhyyyyhmNMMMNhssssssss/    Packages: 2077 (dpkg), 20 (snap) 
.ssssssssdMMMNhsssssssssshNMMMdssssssss.   Shell: zsh /usr/bin/neofetch: line 1669: /usr/bin/zsh: No such file or directory 
+sssshhhyNMMNyssssssssssssyNMMMysssssss+   Resolution: 1920x1080 
ossyNMMMNyMMhsssssssssssssshmmmhssssssso   DE: GNOME 45.0 
ossyNMMMNyMMhsssssssssssssshmmmhssssssso   WM: Mutter 
+sssshhhyNMMNyssssssssssssyNMMMysssssss+   WM Theme: Adwaita 
.ssssssssdMMMNhsssssssssshNMMMdssssssss.   Theme: Yaru-blue-dark [GTK2/3] 
 /sssssssshNMMMyhhyyyyhdNMMMNhssssssss/    Icons: Yaru-blue [GTK2/3] 
  +sssssssssdmydMMMMMMMMddddyssssssss+     Terminal: gnome-terminal 
   /ssssssssssshdmNNNNmyNMMMMhssssss/      CPU: Intel i5-10400F (12) @ 4.300GHz 
    .ossssssssssssssssssdMMMNysssso.       GPU: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060 Lite Hash Rate 
      -+sssssssssssssssssyyyssss+-         Memory: 2550MiB / 15878MiB 
        `:+ssssssssssssssssss+:`
            .-/+oossssoo+/-.
```

Whenever I log into my system, this bug reporting pop-up error message shows up after a couple of minutes.

[image]

Comment: Your title mentioned Ubuntu 23.04 (using the 6.2 kernel), yet your provide details show 23.10 & 6.5 kernel (*as does the wallpaper image you provided via link*).  If you report the issue as requested, you'll be asked to login and the .crash report (*found in `/var/crash`*) will be uploaded and renamed .crash.upload & thus you'll not be asked to report the issue again. If that's pop-up is your only issue, you can delete the .crash file too (*but then it won't be reported and problem cannot be fixed unless other users report it*)

Comment: hey @guiverc sorry for the mistake at the title... I've reported the issue a lots of time as it pops up everytime I start my PC, does that mean I can just delete the `/var/crash/` directory to get rid of this popup?

Comment: No, don't delete the directory; you'll have a **file** in the `/var/crash/` directory that is causing that message to appear. When it's uploaded to the site (ie. which will likely require login to launchpad) the file should be renamed from `.crash` to `.crash.uploaded` (*sorry my directory is empty so have nothing to validate that currently*) which is what causes the message to stop. Just removing the .crash file will also stop the prompt; but please don't remove the directory (*removing the file will work; .crash files in that directory can be removed; esp. after upload*)